# How can I scrape all the results not only first 10 results from just dial search result page using python requests module?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-mining

I want to scrape all the results of the just dial search result page. But I am getting only the first 10 results as it uses lazy loading.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travel-Agents/nct-10496380/page-2'
header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url,headers=header,verify=False)
```

But using this I am able to get only 10 results but I need all the results of that page.
It hits the below URL during lazy load
'https://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination_new&city=Kolkata&search=Travel%20Agents&where=&catid=0&psearch=&prid=&page=3&SID=&mntypgrp=0&toknbkt=&bookDate=&jdsrc=&median_latitude=22.562968864829&median_longitude=88.389698473675&ncatid=10496380&mncatname=Travel%20Agents&dcity=Kolkata&pncode=999999&htlis=0'

When I am using this URL it is returning a blank list.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: use `selenium` along with `beautifulsoup`. Search for "how to scrape dynamic websites"

Comment: Have you try to monitor the network to see how they load data to the page? `Developer Tools>Network` select `XHR` and refresh the page. Scroll down until refresh, and monitor the network. Emulate calls with requests.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Yes I did, from there I got that ajax URL which is being hit when I am scrolling down.  Could you please tell me how can I do it with request module? Is it possible?

Comment: Does it have Response data on DevTools? Is it making only GET call? I am not on PC at the moment :(

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel yes it has but returning blank list when calling it through request module

Comment: It is not Python, as I get same list when you paste the URI on Safari/Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travel-Agents/nct-10496380/page-2'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
match=False
while(match==False):
        lastCount = lenOfPage
        time.sleep(3)
        lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        if lastCount==lenOfPage:
            match=True

li_tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cntanr')
```

The var `li_tags` contains a list of `li` tags. These `li` tags contain the details. You can further parse these li_tags to extract the info. For example, if you want to scrape the `heading` and the `link` of each card displayed on the page, you can add these lines to your code:

```
for li in li_tags:
    print('-'*120)
    a = li.find_element_by_xpath('.//a')
    print(f"Title = {li.find_element_by_class_name('lng_cont_name').text}")
    print(f"Link = {a.get_attribute('href')}")
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = One Solution
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/One-Solution-Near-Shovabazar-Metro-Station-Beadon-Street/033PXX33-XX33-160907152255-Y3S3_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Ashok Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Ashok-Travels-Hatiara/033PXX33-XX33-191014230421-W6S7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Dunia Darshan
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Dunia-Darshan-Near-Hatibagan-Crossing-Beadon-Street/033PXX33-XX33-140329124148-W4R4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = The Traveller
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/The-Traveller-Near-Kathgola-Island-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-2/033PXX33-XX33-121025172529-J4V5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Makemytrip.com
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Makemytrip-com-Opposite-Of-Aminia-Restuarant-Chinarpark-Rajarhat-Gopalpur/033PXX33-XX33-190309193523-K5X9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Maruti Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Maruti-Travels-M-G-Road-Crossing-Central-AV-Burrabazar/033PXX33-XX33-121009122406-W5P2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Land Lopers
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Land-Lopers-Near-S-D-Tower-Prafulla-Kanan/033PXX33-XX33-191116112601-V6B5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Friends Associates
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Friends-Associates-Near-Vivekananda-Women-College-Behala/033P1233643489Y3H8S2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Nature Canvas
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Nature-Canvas-Near-Amrabati-More-Sodepur/033PXX33-XX33-180303183941-D4A2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Millenium Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Millenium-Travels-Opposite-Zeesan-Resturant-Park-Circus/033PXX33-XX33-001191143500-C5Q4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Travel Host Online
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travel-Host-Online-Near-9th-No-Tank-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-2/033PXX33-XX33-180412212504-H3H2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Joy Guru Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Joy-Guru-Tours-Travels-Near-Gariahat-Market-Gariahat/033PXX33-XX33-150405192011-E9S4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Roameos Getaway Private Lim..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Roameos-Getaway-Private-Limited-Besides-ILS-Hospital-Mall-Road/033PXX33-XX33-200107130125-D1N8_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Voyagers Club Tours Pvt Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Voyagers-Club-Tours-Pvt-Ltd-Near-Bata-More-Park-Street/033P400224_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Ticket To Ride
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Ticket-To-Ride-Opp-BOC-Gases-Company-Khidirpur/033PXX33-XX33-191230082015-X9U2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Fly High INDIA Holidays
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Fly-High-INDIA-Holidays-Near-Ganesh-Talkies-Burrabazar/033PXX33-XX33-091013162104-F2V1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = S A Enterprise
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/S-A-Enterprise-Near-Bilal-Masjid-Topsia/033PXX33-XX33-160114133634-F5E1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Anadi Travels Kolkata
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Anadi-Travels-Kolkata-Opposite-Kalighat-TramdepoNear-KC-DAS-Sweet-Kalighat/033PXX33-XX33-180127223006-P3S2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Planet Tourism
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Planet-Tourism/033PXX33-XX33-160822174122-W9S8_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Smooth Trip
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Smooth-Trip-Opposite-Of-1-212-Bus-Stand-Santoshpur/033PXX33-XX33-140114232057-D7H2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Rush24
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Rush24-Opposite-Lalit-Hotel-Dalhousie/033PXX33-XX33-181218160057-T5C1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Door To World Vacation
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Door-To-World-Vacation-Inside-park-plaza-Park-Street/033PXX33-XX33-200429234508-N8G3_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Blue Andaman Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Blue-Andaman-Travels-Near-Quest-Mall-Circus-Avenue/033PXX33-XX33-180606173632-Z6F4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Travellers Partner
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travellers-Partner-Near-Metro-Station-Bansdroni/033PXX33-XX33-160810163021-Y2Y5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Memory Makers
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Memory-Makers-Near-Salt-Lake-Swimming-Pool-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-1/033PXX33-XX33-171221162548-W4F9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Singh International Travel ..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Singh-International-Travel-Service-Near-Burrabazaar-Thana-Kolkata-GPO/033PXX33-XX33-130216193034-S5T4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Getaway Journeys
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Getaway-Journeys-Near-Dhakuria-Bus-Stop-Dhakuria/033PXX33-XX33-160210163357-N2I2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Sahil Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Sahil-Travels-Near-Taleb-Builders-Dum-Dum/033PXX33-XX33-170527133215-U5S5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = India Destinations
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/India-Destinations-Opposite-Coal-India-Dalhousie/033PXX33-XX33-100814152937-D7H5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Mukherjee Travels & Tours
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Mukherjee-Travels-Tours/033PXX33-XX33-190315104054-A9P9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Sgps Tours and Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Sgps-Tours-and-Travels-BADRA-MATH-Italgacha/033PXX33-XX33-140727201943-J6B2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Travellers Desk
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travellers-Desk-Near-16-Jewelles-Club-Agarpara/033PXX33-XX33-160912104454-G5L9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Perfect Tour & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Perfect-Tour-Travels-Near-Swami-Vivekanand-College-Karbala-More-Sonarpur/033PXX33-XX33-110228172229-U2A4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Jmd Tourism and Logistics C..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Jmd-Tourism-and-Logistics-Corporation-Near-Keshtopur-More-Prafulla-Kanan/033PXX33-XX33-160109172126-L1L6_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Hind Travel & Tours
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Hind-Travel-Tours/033PXX33-XX33-100224231656-U3B4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Jai Matadi Travel Service
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Jai-Matadi-Travel-Service-Near-Jhagra-Kothi-Kolkata-GPO/033P400602_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Maruti Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Maruti-Travels-Near-Mukti-Chamber-Dalhousie/033PXX33-XX33-200908174740-B3V2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = S R Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/S-R-Travels-Shahpur/033PXX33-XX33-191205120015-F3B4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Travel India Global Tours &..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travel-India-Global-Tours-Travels-Opposite-Khanna-High-School-Tangra/033PXX33-XX33-130715161538-F4F3_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Memorable Tour and Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Memorable-Tour-and-Travels-Near-Bagbazar-Multipurpose-Girls-High-School-Bagbazar/033PXX33-XX33-190919182126-U4D7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Apex Travels and Tour
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Apex-Travels-and-Tour-Helabottala-Barasat/033PXX33-XX33-180914134059-K1Z2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Happy Hours Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Happy-Hours-Travels-NEAR-KWALITY-BUS-STOP-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-1/033PXX33-XX33-151229164545-M8Y9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Nomadic Holidays
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Nomadic-Holidays-Surendranath-College-Raja-Ram-Mohan-Roy-Sarani/033PXX33-XX33-131212103510-P1T7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Rio Tour And Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Rio-Tour-And-Travels-Near-Hanuman-Mandir-Motijhil/033PXX33-XX33-180121005006-C9T9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Titas Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Titas-Tours-Travels-Near-Aminia-Garia-Garia/033PXX33-XX33-150801153457-I7T6_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Carpet Ride Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Carpet-Ride-Tours-Travels-Near-Abasorika-Club-Dhakuria/033PXX33-XX33-170311124536-N6Q9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Embassy Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Embassy-Travels-Near-Ballygunge-Phari-Ballygunge/033PXX33-XX33-120414172238-K9F2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Nature World Tour & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Nature-World-Tour-Travels-Near-Rajarhat-Police-Station-Lauhati/033PXX33-XX33-181119131503-K7H4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Ambey Travel Services
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Ambey-Travel-Services-Near-Reliance-Fresh-Bangur-Avenue/033PXX33-XX33-180629142608-Q2P8_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Cosmo Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Cosmo-Tours-Travels-Near-Jadavpur-Railway-Station-Santoshpur/033P1220521168L3M9M5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Seabird Tours And Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Seabird-Tours-And-Travels-Opposite-South-City-Mall-Lake-Gardens/033PXX33-XX33-100608123537-J4E1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Mount Kailash Travel Desk
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Mount-Kailash-Travel-Desk-Rashmoni-Bazaar-Beliaghata/033PXX33-XX33-170419094346-D4C7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Kra Tours and Travel Pvt Lt..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Kra-Tours-and-Travel-Pvt-Ltd-Opposite-Ladies-Park-Entally/033PXX33-XX33-130320163030-Z8Z8_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Travel Crafters(oihik)
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Travel-Craftersoihik-Near-LIC-Building-Bowbazar/033PXX33-XX33-180527120622-Z9C7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Arya Solutions
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Arya-Solutions-Near-Khadims-Kabardanga-Joka/033PXX33-XX33-170110110919-V6J4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Sailayee Tours And Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Sailayee-Tours-And-Travels-Near-Beckbagan-Mithai-Bus-Stop-Ballygunge/033PXX33-XX33-110615104346-Q9D3_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = The Traveller
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/The-Traveller-Near-AE-Market-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-1/033PXX33-XX33-180430133259-R1M1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Akash Tourism
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Akash-Tourism-Near-No-5-Bus-Stand-Garia-More-Garia/033P401591_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = New Lakshmi Enterprise
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/New-Lakshmi-Enterprise-Bhawanipur/033PXX33-XX33-160509161339-D4A1_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Ganapati Trading
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Ganapati-Trading-Near-13A-Bus-Stand-Sarkarpool/033PXX33-XX33-180420221513-P6W2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = NIL NIRJONE TOURS & TRAVELS
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Bardhaman/NIL-NIRJONE-TOURS-TRAVELS-Bharat-Sevashram-Sangha-Burdwan/9999PX342-X342-190607125020-I9M9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Istaqbal Tour & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Balaghat/Istaqbal-Tour-Travels-Near-By-Treasure-Cenima-Baihar/9999P7632-7632-180206082550-M7J6_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Royal Tripmaker
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Bokaro/Royal-Tripmaker-Bokaro-City/9999P6542-6542-140430144231-B4L9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Abtesa Enterprises
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Abtesa-Enterprises-Gurgaon/011PXX11-XX11-190723180224-H2F5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = New Prantik Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/New-Prantik-Tours-Travels-Near-SBI-Sonarpur-Sonarpur/033PXX33-XX33-200213122427-K6B9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Incredible Tours & Travels
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Solan/Incredible-Tours-Travels-Opp-Durga-Club-Chowk-Bazar/9999P1792-1792-140523121451-V4N6_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Via.com
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Via-com-New-Delhi/011P73691_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Makemytrip.com ( Branch Off..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Makemytrip-com-Branch-Office-Near-Minto-Park-Crossing-Lala-Lajpat-Rai-Sarani/033PXX33-XX33-110609112614-M8V6_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Royal Cruiser Pvt Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Royal-Cruiser-Pvt-Ltd-Near-Indian-Museum-Park-Street/033PXX33-XX33-100626182143-P9W8_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Thomas Cook India Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Thomas-Cook-India-Ltd-Near-AJC-Bose-College-Midleton-Row/033PXX33-XX33-171220002751-K3S3_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Kundu Special
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Kundu-Special-Beside-Cesc-Head-Office-Chandni-Chowk/033PXX33-XX33-110722184548-B1D7_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Cox & Kings Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Cox-Kings-Ltd-Near-Jeevandeep-Midleton-Row/033PXX33-XX33-100827121238-W1B9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Council Service Station
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Council-Service-Station-Near-Burdwan-Road-Majerhat-Crossing-Alipore/033P6853218_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Thomas Cook India Ltd (Trav..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Thomas-Cook-India-Ltd-Travel-Division-Near-South-City-Mall-Ram-Mohan-Mission-School-Lords-More-Lake-Gardens/033PXX33-XX33-120619160943-X2Y4_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Denzong Leisure Pvt Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Denzong-Leisure-Pvt-Ltd-Opposite-Nonapukur-Tram-Depot-Circus-Avenue/033PXX33-XX33-130723154502-Y4C5_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Jatrik Travel Agency
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Jatrik-Travel-Agency-Near-Lal-Bazar-Head-Quarter-Bowbazar/033PF001118_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Gainwell Enterprises Pvt Lt..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Gainwell-Enterprises-Pvt-Ltd-Near-Gaja-Park-Bhawanipur-Lala-Lajpat-Rai-Sarani/033PF002375_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Chalo Jaai Travel Club (Hea..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Chalo-Jaai-Travel-Club-Head-Office-Near-Tata-Center-Midleton-Row/033PXX33-XX33-120402174905-T4A9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Indian Railway Catering & T..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Indian-Railway-Catering-Tourism-Corporation-Ltd-Opposite-Gpo-Irtc-East-Zone-Kolkata-Gpo/033P6006614_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Cox & Kings Ltd
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Cox-Kings-Ltd-Beside-Bijya-Bank-atm-Park-Street/033PF002438_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Himachal Pradesh Tourism De..
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Himachal-Pradesh-Tourism-Development-Corporation-Ltd-Near-Sabir-Hotel-Chandni-Chowk/033P5001950_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Arunachal Pradesh Tourism
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Arunachal-Pradesh-Tourism-Salt-Lake-City-Sector-1/033P5000222_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Yatra.com (retail Office)
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Yatra-com-retail-Office-Near-Park-Hotel-Park-Street/033PXX33-XX33-100524111359-U6R2_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Shohagh Paribahan
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Shohagh-Paribahan-Park-Street/033PXX33-XX33-180809191256-X8G9_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Title = Himalchura Travels & Tours
Link = https://www.justdial.com/Kolkata/Himalchura-Travels-Tours-Near-State-Bank-Of-India-Beliaghata/033P6007608_BZDET?xid=S29sa2F0YSBUcmF2ZWwgQWdlbnRz&tab=gallery
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with request module ?

Comment: I am not sure about it. But the best way to scrape such websites is to use ```selenium```. Just copy paste my code into ur editor and let me know whether it works.

Comment: @Sushil very naive question ..I use mostly R ..so how do you run the first part of your code ..Jupyter notebook will it work? or i need something else

Comment: @PesKchan Sorry but i cant help u with this, bc i have never written a single line of `R` in my life :( U can try converting my `python` code into `R`. If u couldn't, then u can post it as a separate question.